# Invisible border on images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, border

I'm trying to separate my 10 random images a little bit so they're not squished and all together. I tried using a border, I'm not getting any errors, it's just that it's not working. I'm trying to use the border as padding, so it must be invisible and only on the left and right. Any help?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cards</title>
    <script type="text/css">
     .cardPad{
      border-top:none;
      border-bottom:none;
      border-left:10px;
      border-right:10px;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
     <?php 
      $cards = array("Messi", "Ronaldo", "Ibrahimovic", "Ribery", "Robben", "Neymar", "Rooney", "Casillas", "Falcao", "Van Persie", "Hazard", "Iniesta", "Xavi", "Schweinsteiger", "Silva", "Fabregas", "Lahm", "Aguero", "Cavani", "Vidic", "Ozil", "Mata", "Bale", "ThiagoSilva", "Kompany", "Tevez", "Toure", "Ramos", "Suarez", "Pirlo", "DiMaria", "Neuer", "Pique", "Buffon", "Lewandowski", "Gomez", "Chiellini", "Cole", "Pedro", "Busquets", "Cech", "Muller", "Hummels", "Alonso", "Navas", "Modric", "Cazorla", "Gotze", "Benzema", "Vidal", "Lavezzi");

shuffle($cards);

$cards = array_slice($cards, 0, 10);

foreach ($cards as $card) {
    echo "<img class='cardPad' src='http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/fit/105x97/http://clearpkz.webs.com/webstore/$card.png'>";
}
?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give fiddle demo ?

Comment: @Nish Not sure if I set it up properly, but here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/N8pVn/

Comment: @Journey please see my jsfiddle. You have to use HTML not PHP in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enclose the stylesheet in `<style>` tag and not `<script>` tag.

```
<style>
     .cardPad {
       border:10px solid #00f;
       border-bottom:0;
       border-top:0;
      }
</style>
```

And you need to specify a border style for it to apply. Like "solid", "dashed" etc. The color by default would be #000. I have changed it to blue for clarity.

For padding purposes, use the padding/margin property and not border. For an img, both would give the same effect however actually the two are different. Which would look like this

```
<style>
     .cardPad{
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
</style>
```

You can see the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/Ukp6z/2/

If you are hell bent on using border, though not the correct way-

Then use

```
<style>
     .cardPad{
       border:10px solid transparent;
       border-bottom:0;
       border-top:0;

      }
</style>
```

This would give the same effect as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/Ukp6z/3/

Answer (score 2):

I created a jsfiddle for this, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alansalexer/4C8Bx/1/) what you want?

Actually, you can use `margin` or `padding` to separate these `<img>`s. I don't get why you can't get it work.

You may need to post your modified code so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks, it was a stupid mistake as others pointed out, I tried to make a CSS <script> instead of <style> lol. It was one in the morning for me so I was drained. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
 .cardPad{
    ...
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Like Rahul wrote, you need to set the style for the class "cardPad" in your head.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cardPad{
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

I copied your code and uploaded to my server, and I believe this change would give you the effect you desire.

Comment: I dont think we need type attribute in the style tag if it is "text/css". That is assumed by default.

Comment: That is correct at present. I still generally include it for forward-compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use one (or more) the following CSS properties on your item?

```
margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom, margin-left, padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom and padding-left
```

e.g.

```
h2 {
font-size: 1.5em;
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 20px;
padding: 40px;
}
```

This page has more info -> http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

Comment: Hmm, still not working for me. I think it's because it's php but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The code's wrong (needs style instead of script tag) and overall spacing should be defined by `padding` or `margin` instead of `border`, but replace that `<script type="text/css"></script>` tag with this and it should work:

```
<style>
.cardPad {
    border-left:10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-right:10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
</style>
```